# Writing a class as a helper service and calling it from another class

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand how to approach this in Swift.

Say for example I have the following UIViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let logoutButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onPressLogout), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Logged in"

        view.addSubview(logoutButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            logoutButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            logoutButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    @objc fileprivate func onPressLogout() {
        AuthService.logOut()
    }
}
```

and an AuthService

```
final class AuthService {
    static func logOut() -> Void {
        print("Logout Pressed")
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is call `logOut` on my `AuthService` when `onPressLogout` is pressed.

What I am trying to understand is how should I get access to `logOut` in the correct and best possible way.

For example, as I have now? A static method on the class?

Should I instead create an instance of it like

```
lazy var auth = AuthService()
```

and then call logout via `auth.logOut()` without the `static` keyword?

I am confused as to what the best approach is for creating these 'helper' classes.

Comment: You’re asking the wrong question. Your code has a fatal flaw : your `onPressLogout` will never be called at all!  So you can never call your helper or anything else. Your button is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a singleton is a common practice.

For testability, I would recommend injecting your AuthService as a dependency. First I would create a protocol:

```
protocol AuthServiceProtocol {
    func logOut()
}
```

Then I would make my service conform to that protocol. (Note: this class could be set up as a singleton, it really doesn't matter for my purpose here, which is to demonstrate dependency injection.)

```
class AuthService: AuthServiceProtocol {
    func logOut() {
        print("Logout Pressed")
    }
}
```

I would add a class-level variable to my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var authService: AuthServiceProtocol?

    //existing code...
}
```

The logout function would need to change as follows:

```
@objc fileprivate func onPressLogout() {
    authService?.logOut()
}
```

After creating the view controller, I would pass the service into it:

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.authService = AuthService()
```

That's it. I can test this in a playground like so:

```
//TEST by forcing view to load and sending fake button touch event
let _ = vc.view
vc.logoutButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

//prints... "Logout Pressed"
```

Now I can write a real unit test that passes in a mock service that doesn't have  dependencies. This allows me to test my view controller more reliably.

Comment: I think you went a bit too far with that protocol. Injecting `AuthService` externally is a good idea but why the protocol?

Comment: For unit testing it is valuable not to use the real service but a mock. The real service probably depends on external data or network that is hard to control.

Comment: I know but it will also make your whole app full of unnecessary protocols which need to be maintained and are implemented by one class only. Don't *unit test* UI.  Create integration tests for UI, that is, write a test that will actually click the button in a running application instance. You cannot unit test UI because UI is just a connector between UIKit, your data model and services, therefore your test would end up duplicating your UI code. Been there, it's not a good idea. Great code coverage but no bugs actually caught.

Comment: OK, we can disagree. I've unit tested view controllers with some success. UI is not any different than other code. It's still code you write that can have bugs. Maybe your UI code is bug-free, but I've caught bugs in my code using this technique.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact usage of AuthService but you may consider writing it in a [Singleton](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift) pattern.

This guarantees that only one instance of the class is initiated. examples of singleton patterns: `URLSession.shared`, `UserDefaults.standard`

That way you'll be able to access it in a way like `AuthService.shared.logout()` or `AuthService.shared.isUserLoggedIn`

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps approach this using a [singleton](https://medium.com/@nimjea/singleton-class-in-swift-17eef2d01d88).

```
struct AuthService {

    static let shared: AuthService = {
        return AuthService()
    }()

    func logOut() -> Void {
        print("Logout Pressed")
    }
}
```

This would allow you to call your method like `AuthService.shared.logOut()`

Comment: `static let shared`. It should be a constant.